# VBA: Editing Word document with Excel gives run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

In spite of heavy googling, I am not able to figure out, what is wrong with this. Do I still miss a reference or something? If you can see, where the error lies, I'll be forever grateful!

References:

- Visual Basic For Applications
- Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
- RefEdit Control
- Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library

Variables:

```
Public appWord As Word.Application
Public sapmWord As Word.Document

Dim asNimi As String 'in this current sub
```

Code:

```
On Error Resume Next

Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
appWord.Visible = True
Set sapmWord = appWord.documents.Open("C:\ThisIsWorking\andDocOpens.docx")
'sapmWord.Activate 'doesn't make a difference

With sapmWord
    Selection.EndKey Unit = wdStory 'this line is first line to give an error. With or without a dot in the beginning of line.
    Selection.TypeText Text:=asNimi 'this line too, if previous is commented
'...and so on!
End With

sapmWord.Close savechanges:=True
Set appWord = Nothing
Set sapmWord = Nothing
```

Comment: Change `wdStory` to `6`.

Comment: Mouseover tells me, that it recognizes it, "wdStory=6"

Comment: @FunTHomas's suggestion should fix the problem/error you ask in your Question. The rule on Stack Overflow is: one question / Question - don't start adding on. If new problems crop up, ask a new Question. If the new question bases on important info in an earlier question, link to that question or re-post the info.

Comment: There's no new problems, just this one and unfortunately none of these advices help. In this case mouseover means VBA own tracking.

Comment: What is your actual problem? I used your code with the changes I suggested in my answer and it worked.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work, and I can't figure out why. But I found another way:
sapmWord.Activate
sapmWord.Range.InsertAfter asNimi

Comment: What do you mean with "*doesn't work*". Compiler error? Runtime error? Executing but doing the wrong thing? Executing but doing nothing?

Comment: The same 438 error remains. The problem seems to be the Word file it self, it has to columns and for some reason VBA through Excel seems to treat it as a table. What a pain.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you're trying to do. Like: if you were to open the document in Word and make the change you need as a user, what would you be doing?

Comment: I open existing Word document - that's working fine. Then I want to add text to the end of that document, and that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`sapmWord` is a word document. A word document doesn't have a `selection` method. The Word application object has it, so probably you mean (and yes, you need the '.')

```
With appWord 
    .Selection.EndKey Unit:= wdStory 
    .Selection.TypeText Text:=asNimi 
    '...and so on!
End With
```

Comment: Next problem: Since we are using late binding here, the `Word` constant `wdStory` is not known and must be set to be `6` first. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdunits-enumeration-word.

Comment: Since the OP wrote `appWord As Word.Application` as variable declaration, I assume he has added a reference to the Word Object Library

Comment: The OP has added the reference, but then uses late binding to create the Word object so I'm not sure if `appWord` has access to the references.

Comment: I tested the code and it works. I think the `wdStory` is not seen by the Word App but by the VBA compiler that translates it to the underlying value.

Comment: Good stuff.  Didn't know if it would or not.  Found this which agrees with you - [to manipulate an existing instance of Excel (if Excel is already open) you would use GetObject (regardless whether you're using early or late binding)](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/InterDev/EarlyvsLateBinding.htm)

Comment: This change (with appWord instead of with sapmWord) gave me "run-time error 4120: Bad parameter".

Comment: You have to use `:=` to assign a value to a named parameter, so use `Unit:=wdStory`

Comment: And I had both app and document declared as Objects earlier, I tried to fix this 438 problem changing them as app and document.

Comment: Changing them will help you find errors (because intellisense will support you), but  if an object doesn't have a method it doesn't have a method...

Answer (score 1):

You have to change sapmWord.Close savechanges:=True for appWord.quit savechanges:=True

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwis please add an explanation how this works and why it is supposed to solve the problem. Answers with explanations are usually perceived as more helpful and it would also help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

To use `With`, you must reference members with a `.`:

```
With sapmWord
    .Selection.EndKey Unit = wdStory
    .Selection.TypeText Text:=asNimi
End With
```

Comment: Next problem: Since we are using late binding here, the `Word` constant `wdStory` is not known and must be set to be `6` first. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdunits-enumeration-word.

Comment: @AxelRichter Maybe, but lego is mixing references with late binding, so probably wdStory is defined in Word library.

Comment: Adding dots and changing wdStory to 6 don't make a difference, same run-time error 438 remains.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I had no choice but adding bookmarks to the Word document and filling them with VBA. I still have no clue why those original codes did not work in my code, although they work for others. Thank you all for help, maybe some one else is getting answers here anyway.